# Java проблема с кодировкой

Tags: java, кодировка

Если запускать через консоль так:
java  -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar printerFX.jar

кодировка нормальная. Мне нужно что бы работало без запуска из консоли, как это вылечить?

```
package sample;

import sample.printserv.ServerTLS;
import sample.printserv.messages.PrintableConfig;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.net.*;

public class Main {

    public static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "Print server";
    public static final String ICON_STR = "Print.png";
    static ServerTLS serverTLS;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                createGUI();
            }
        });
    }

    private static void createGUI() {
//        JFrame frame = new JFrame(APPLICATION_NAME);
//        frame.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(300, 200));
//        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
//        frame.pack();
//        frame.setVisible(true);

        serverTLS = new ServerTLS();

        Thread myThready = new Thread(serverTLS);   //Создание потока "myThready"
        myThready.start();
        setTrayIcon();
    }

    private static void setTrayIcon() {
        PrintableConfig prConf = new PrintableConfig();
        if(! SystemTray.isSupported() ) {
            return;
        }

        PopupMenu trayMenu = new PopupMenu();
        MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Exit");
        item.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });
        trayMenu.add(item);

        URL imageURL = Main.class.getResource(prConf.PrinterPNG);

        Image icon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageURL);
        TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(icon, APPLICATION_NAME, trayMenu);
        trayIcon.setImageAutoSize(true);

        SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();
        try {
            tray.add(trayIcon);
        } catch (AWTException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        trayIcon.displayMessage(APPLICATION_NAME, "Application started!",
                TrayIcon.MessageType.INFO);
    }
}
```

Часть тлс

```
package sample.printserv;

import com.alibaba.fastjson.JSON;
import sample.printserv.cut.PrintWithoutDialog;
import sample.printserv.messages.PrintableConfig;
import sample.printserv.messages.StructPrintable;

import javax.net.ssl.*;
import javax.print.*;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.Copies;
import java.awt.print.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.util.Date;

public class ServerTLS implements Runnable{
    //java  -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar PrintWithJava.jar
    public static PrintService findPrintService(String printerName)
    {
        System.out.println("Search printer: " + printerName);
        for (PrintService service : PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices())
        {
            if (service.getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerName))
                return service;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public void run() {
        PrintableConfig prConf = new PrintableConfig();


        try {
            System.setErr(new PrintStream(new File("log.log")));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.err.println("------------------------------------");
        System.err.println(new Date().toString()+" - RUN SERVER");


        String host = prConf.Host;
        int port = prConf.HostPort;

        // CREATE SSLContext
        // create key store
        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(prConf.FileCert),prConf.PassCert.toCharArray());

            // create key manager
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            keyManagerFactory.init(keyStore, prConf.PassJKS.toCharArray());
            KeyManager[] km = keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers();

            // create trust manager
            TrustManagerFactory trustManagerFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            trustManagerFactory.init(keyStore);
            TrustManager[] tm = trustManagerFactory.getTrustManagers();

            // init SSLContext
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");
            sslContext.init(km, tm, null);

            // create socket
            SSLServerSocketFactory sslServerSocketFactory = (SSLServerSocketFactory) sslContext.getServerSocketFactory();
            SSLServerSocket sslServerSocket = (SSLServerSocket) sslServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket(7730);

            String exit = "";
            System.out.println("SSL server started");

            while (true){

                SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslServerSocket.accept();

                InputStream inputStream = sslSocket.getInputStream();


                OutputStream outputStream = sslSocket.getOutputStream();

                DataInputStream bufferedReader = new DataInputStream(inputStream);

                PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream));


                byte[] buf = new byte[4];
                bufferedReader.read(buf);
                Integer i = Integer.valueOf(new String(buf));
                String string = "";
                try {
                    buf = new byte[i];
                    bufferedReader.readFully(buf);
                    System.out.println(new String(buf,prConf.EncodingGet));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.err.println(new Date().toString()+" - "+e);
                    string = String.valueOf(("00:"+e.toString()).getBytes().length);
                    while(string.length()<4){string="0" + string;}
                    printWriter.print(string+"00:"+e.toString());
                    continue;
                }
                string = new String(buf);
                StructPrintable sPrint;
                try {
                    sPrint = JSON.parseObject(string, StructPrintable.class);
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.err.println(new Date().toString()+"  - "+e);
                    string = String.valueOf(("00:"+e.toString()).getBytes().length);
                    while(string.length()<4){string="0"+string;}
                    printWriter.print(string+"00:"+e.toString());
                    continue;
                }

                PrintService service = findPrintService(prConf.Printers.get(sPrint.OrgHash));
                if (service==null){
                    System.out.println("Not found printer "+sPrint.OrgHash);
                    service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
                    if (service==null){
                        System.out.println("Not found default printer");
                    }{
                        System.out.println("Found default printer: "+service.getName());
                    }
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Found printer: " + service.getName());
                }
                if (service!=null){
                    //PrintService service = PrintServiceLookup.lookupDefaultPrintService();
                    DocPrintJob job = service.createPrintJob();

                    DocFlavor flavor = DocFlavor.BYTE_ARRAY.AUTOSENSE;

                    Doc doc;
                    try{

                        string = "------------------------------------------\n" +
                                sPrint.Header + "\n" + sPrint.InfoOrg + "\n";
                        if (!sPrint.InfoCheck.isEmpty()) {
                            string += sPrint.InfoCheck + "\n";
                        }
                        string += "   ************************************\n";
                        for (String entry : sPrint.Body) {
                            if (entry!=null) {
                                string += entry+"\n";
                            }
                        }
                        string += "   ************************************\n";

                        string+=sPrint.Thanks+"\n";
                        string+="   ************************************\n";
                        string+=sPrint.Footer+"\n";

                        doc = new SimpleDoc(string.getBytes(prConf.EncodingPrint), flavor, null);
                    }catch (Exception e ){
                        System.err.println(new Date().toString()+" - "+e);
                        System.out.println("Exception  doc = new SimpleDoc: "+e);
                        string = String.valueOf(("00:"+e.toString()).getBytes().length);
                        while(string.length()<4){string="0"+string;}
                        printWriter.print(string+"00:"+e.toString());
                        continue;
                    }
                    PrintRequestAttributeSet attrs = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                    attrs.add(new Copies(1));

                    try {
                        job.print(doc, attrs);
                    } catch (PrintException e) {
                        System.err.println(new Date().toString()+" - "+e);
                        System.out.println("Exception job.print(doc, attrs);: " + e);
                        string = String.valueOf(("00:"+e.toString()).getBytes().length);
                        while(string.length()<4){string="0"+string;}
                        printWriter.print(string+"00:"+e.toString());
                        continue;
                    }
                }
                PrintWithoutDialog pr = new PrintWithoutDialog(service);
                buf = new byte[4096];


                string = String.valueOf("01:OK".getBytes().length);
                while(string.length()<4){string="0"+string;}
                printWriter.print(string+"01:OK");
                printWriter.flush();

            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}

//windows-1251
//UTF-8
//CP1251
//KOI8_R
//Cp866 - working
                        /*
                                Cp1251:
                        Windows-1251
                        Cp866:
                        IBM866
                        IBM-866
                        866
                        CP866
                        CSIBM866
                                KOI8_R:
                        KOI8-R
                        KOI8
                        CSKOI8R
                                ISO8859_5:
                        ISO8859-5
                        ISO-8859-5
                        ISO_8859-5
                        ISO_8859-5:1988
                        ISO-IR-144
                        8859_5
                        Cyrillic
                        CSISOLatinCyrillic
                        IBM915
                        IBM-915
                        Cp915
                        915
                        */
```

Comment: По всей видимости в приложении printerFX.jar использует кодировка по-умолчанию. Перепишите приложение, чтобы в нём кодировка явно задавалась как `UTF-8`. Если нет возможности переписать приложение, то сделайте bat (для Windows) или sh (для Linux) файл, который запускает это приложение с нужными параметрами, как вы описали. И запускайте этот скрипт.

Comment: Как это сделать?

Comment: Как задать явно?

Comment: Чтобы ответить на ваш вопрос, нужно проанализировать исходный код приложения printerFX.jar. Там, где вы работаете с потоками ввода/вывода, при чтении и записи явно задавайте кодировку UTF-8.

Comment: Выложил два файла

Comment: обратите внимание на эту строку: `doc = new SimpleDoc(string.getBytes(prConf.EncodingPrint), flavor, null);`, а в частности на `prConf.EncodingPrint`. Какое значение скрывается за `prConf.EncodingPrint` ?

Comment: cp866 чтобы печатало из консоли нормально. Но когда я запускаю не из консоли я так и не смог подобрать кодировку для нормальной печати на принтере. Печатает всякое г

Comment: как я понимаю, вот здесь: `job.print(doc, attrs);` вы отправляете на печать объект `doc`, который построен на основании строки с кодировкой `cp866`. То есть на печать у вас уходит документ с кодировкой отличной от `UTF-8`.

Comment: Именно, но с кодировкой utf-8 у меня выходят символы отличные от оригинальной строки которую он должен напечатать

Comment: Если вы запускаете приложение без `-Dfile.encoding="UTF-8"`, что происходит?

Comment: Печатается строка отличная от оригинальной
вот ссылка на гит если сильно интересно

https://github.com/SantFlamel/printerFX

Comment: К сожалению у меня нет возможности детально разбираться с вашим проектом. Какая-то часть выполняемого кода требует, чтобы кодировка JVM по-умолчанию была `UTF-8`, в то время, как другой части вашего кода для корректной работы требуется кодировка `cp866`. Где конкретно в коде надо искать проблему, я затрудняюсь ответить.

Comment: по tls передаются сообщения из golang в кодировке utf-8, java принимает сообщение и так как работает из командной строки то видимо для нормальной печати требует кодировку в cp866 в противном случае печатает строку отличную от оригинальной

Comment: `string = new String(buf);` - вот тут используется кодировка по-умолчанию, попробуйте указать явно, как в коде выше

Answer (score 0):

В общем я просто сделал батник и vbs файл раз работает то оставил так

VBS

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "run.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

ватник

```
@echo off
java  -Dfile.encoding="cp866" -jar printerFX_jar.jar
```